# Counting Problem Pigeon Hole Principle?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Problem: I bought 10 bat and 15 pumpkin decorations.  I give these decorations names so they are all unique. I came home and realized I can only hang 6 decorations on my walls. If I don't care what I hang up, how many are there to select that I can hang on my walls if:

1. I would like to hang up at least as many pumpkins as bats?

   **Solution:** I just said that you could hang up $10\cdot9\cdot8$ bats and $15\cdot14\cdot13$ pumpkins.
2. I would like like to hang up an equal number of bats and pumpkins on my walls, but I can't hang up "Frank" the bat without "Emma" the pumpkin.

   **Solution:** I hang up one pair of distinctive pair of bats and pumpkins so I thought: $1\cdot9\cdot8$ bats and $1\cdot14\cdot13$ pumpkins.

My question here is can you use the Pigeon Hole Principle here? I don't know how to apply it to certain situations. I was thinking that you have your objects, the pumpkins and the bats, and your holes, the wall. Above a correct way to think about it or doing the Pigeon Hole Principle be easier?

Comment: These are not Pigeonhole Principle problems.  In the first problem, if you hang up at least as many pumpkins as bats, you either hang up three pumpkins and three bats, four pumpkins and two bats, five pumpkins and one bat, or six pumpkins.  For the second problem, consider cases depending on whether or not you hang up "Frank" the bat.  In both problems, the order of selection does not matter, just which pumpkins and which bats you hang up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, you have to consider that you can hang up $4$ pumpkins and $2$ bats, or $5$ pumpkins and $1$ bat, or $6$ pumpkins and $0$ bats.  You don't have to split them evenly because it asks for "at least as many," not the same number.  Thus, you have to count each case.  For the $(3,3)$ case, there are $\binom{15}{3}$ ways to pick three pumpkins out of the $15$ available, and $\binom{10}{3}$ ways to pick three bats out of the $10$ available; and since the choices of pumpkins and bats can be made completely independently and result in a unique combination, there are $$\binom{15}{3}\binom{10}{3}$$ ways to choose six decorations in which exactly three are bats and three are pumpkins.

Then we repeat this for the other cases and add them all up to get $$\binom{15}{3}\binom{10}{3} + \binom{15}{4} \binom{10}{2} + \binom{15}{5}\binom{10}{1} + \binom{15}{6} \binom{10}{0}$$ total possibilities.

Note that the problem doesn't actually explicitly state that you must hang six decorations in total--it only says you have space for six.  So it is unclear whether you allow cases where there are fewer than six decorations hung in total.

As for the second part, you simply eliminate one of the possible choices for each bat and pumpkin as these are predetermined.  This leads to $$\binom{14}{2} \binom{9}{2}$$ possibilities.